# How to correct the degrees of freedom?

Tags: r, anova, degrees-of-freedom

I'm running mixed design ANOVA using R.
Somehow, I got incorrect values for the degrees of freedom (Df). There are two factors: `temperature` (2 levels) and `identity` (7 levels) and when I perform this command :

`aov4<- aov(NO3.means~temperature*identity,data=mydata)`

I get:

```
                     Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
temperature           1 3936158 3936158  24.519 1.54e-05 ***
identity              1   71125   71125   0.443  0.50967    
temperature:identity  1 1363345 1363345   8.493  0.00595 ** 
Residuals            38 6100236  160533                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

the degrees of freedom for identity should be 6 rather than 1. What is the problem?

Comment: `is.numeric(mydata$identity)` will presumably give `TRUE` when it should give `FALSE` (you need it to be a factor). See `?factor` and `?as.factor`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your `identity` variable is treated like a numerical variable instead of a factor (categorical) variable. Using your code, one way to fix this would be:

```
mydata$identity <- as.factor(mydata$identity)
aov4 <- aov(NO3.means ~ temperature*identity, data=mydata)
summary(aov4)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, same thing as the poster faced happened to me but your suggestion does not seem to be working.